# Is there a way to negate message.content?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot remove all messages from one specific channel if it doesn't begin with 'play!'.

I have tried `(message.channel === (channel number) && !message.content.('play!'))`. This does not seem to work.

```
bot.on('message', message=>{

    //delete all in channel if not beginning with play! starts here
    if (message.channel === (the channel) && !message.content.('play!')) {
        message.delete(50);
    }
    // and ends here
})
```

I expect it to delete all messages that do not begin with play! and are in the channel.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
if (message.channel === (the channel) && !message.content.startsWith('play!')) {
    return message.delete(50);
}
```

So `!message.content.startsWith('play!')` and `return message.delete(50);` to delete the message and to stop doing anything else with the message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
if (message.channel === (the channel) && message.content !== "play!") {
    message.delete(50);
}
```

or if you want to check if the content starts with "play!":

```
if (message.channel === (the channel) && !message.content.startsWith("play!")) {
    message.delete(50);
}
```